# Japanese IME is behaving strangely (MS Word 2013)

Tags: microsoft-word, language, input-languages

I'm trying to type Japanese inside my MS Word 2013 documents. However, the Japanese text appeared in a small draggable box, originally on the top left corner of my screen, instead of inline where I'm typing like it should be. I tried doing it on Notepad and it appeared correctly.

Is there a setting in MS Word 2013 / MS Office 2013 that made the Japanese IME behaving this way? And if there is, can I somehow change it back to inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is an option to activate direct input mode in Japanese IME. Here is the steps to do so (using Windows 7 as sample):

a. **Using language bar**

Click the drop down button on bottom-right corner of language bar while Japanese IME is being active, click "Properties" to add the menu, then click on it when appears.

[image: IME Properties Menu]

When dialog box "Properties for Microsoft IME" appears, go to "Editing" tab, then uncheck "Don't use direct input mode" (as shown in supplementary image).

[image: IME Properties Editing tab]

b. **Using "Region & Language Options"**

Go to Control Panel => Region & Language => Keyboards & Languages tab => click "Change keyboards" button. The "Text Services & Input Languages" dialog box will appear as shown below:

[image]

Select "Japanese - Microsoft IME" & click "Properties" button, then "Properties for Microsoft IME" dialog box will appear and follow same procedure above to uncheck "Don't use direct input mode" option.

NB: Don't forget to apply changes using "Apply" then "OK" button and restart all Office applications which exhibit that small input popup box.

Related issue:

[Weirdness with Japanese IME and MS Outlook (also apply for other MS Office programs)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8/weirdness-with-japanese-ime-and-ms-outlook/bf82a65a-16b6-4fb8-81b3-9808140f3fe2)